# What is best practice for updating "New Item" on SharePoint form for a custom content type?

Tags: sharepoint, label, content-type

When creating a new list item based on a content type, the "New" dropdown box gives you a list of custom content types to choose from. When selecting the content type, you're taken to a form to fill out. At the top of this form it says "New Item."

What is best practice for updating this label to show the actual content type name rather than just "New Item?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to options to edit the forms of a SharePoint list. If you only want to change the form for a specific list then you could change the SharePoint designer to edit the forms. 
http://kalsing.blogspot.com/2006/11/create-custom-list-form-for-sharepoint.html

If you have defined your content type as a feature then you could define a new, edit and display form within this feature, that'll be used every time you use this custom content type.